# How to use MYSQL Trigger with Cursor

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Want to Insert multiple rows into table "txn_dbtransactionnotification" when new data is inserted/update into the "Txn_Sales" table.
Suppose 5 rows are present into the transaction table "Txn_Sales" and 1 row into the master table "Mst_Sales".
So when Data into the master table "Mst_Sales" is modified then related data into the table "Txn_Sales" must be modified and the update be sent to the table "txn_dbtransactionnotification" so how can I use a Cursor inside a Trigger so when data in table "Mst_Sales" is modified then data into the table "Txn_Sales" must be modified row by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor support is incomplete in MySQL's stored routine language. It does not support `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF CURSOR` like some other brands of SQL implementation.

But in many cases, it's not necessary to update row by row. It's simpler to update a batch. Think of updating sets of rows, instead of row by row.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER UPDATE ON Mst_Sales
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- update a set of rows related to the same product that
  -- spawned this trigger. 
  UPDATE Txn_Sales SET price = NEW.price WHERE product = NEW.product;

  -- and enter a record in the notifications table
  INSERT INTO txn_dbtransactionnotification ...;
END
```

I had to imagine what type of update you were talking about, because you described the problem in such an abstract way. In a real-life scenario, I don't think changing the price of a product would apply retroactively to past transactions. So the example above is only to show the technique, not the real code you would use.